# Visualise planes in RealityKit with texture of a repeating image

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to detect planes and I want to cover detected planes with an image that repeats. Right now I am able to get the image to cover the detected plane but instead of repeating to cover the plane, the image is stretched to fill the plane.

This is part of my code to place the image to cover a detected plane.

```
fileprivate func didSetup() {
    self.planeGeometry = .generatePlane(width: planeAnchor.extent.x,
                                        depth: planeAnchor.extent.z)
    var material = SimpleMaterial()
    material.color = try! .init(tint: .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5),
                                texture: .init(.load(named: "white_dot.png")))
    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: planeGeometry, materials: [material])
    model.position = [planeAnchor.center.x, 0, planeAnchor.center.z]
    self.addChild(model)
}
```

In addition to this, I have a didUpdate() portion to update the size of the image as planes are updated.

This produces one stretched image instead of the image repeating to fill the plane which is what I want.

I've read that there is something about MTLSamplerAddressMode that might help me achieve what I want but due to the lack of useful documentation, I do not know how to use it.

Can someone point me in the right direction and share resources I can refer to? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

So after some more digging around some documentation, I found out about PhysicallyBasedMaterial being able to get a repeating texture. All I had to do was to set the `material.textureCoordinateTransform.scale` to achieve the repeating pattern.

```
fileprivate func didSetup() {
    self.planeGeometry = .generatePlane(width: planeAnchor.extent.x,
                                        depth: planeAnchor.extent.z)

    let texture = try! MaterialParameters.Texture(.load(named: "white_dot.png"))
    var material = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
    material.baseColor = .init(tint: .white, texture: texture)
    material.blending = .transparent(opacity: .init(floatLiteral:Float(0.5)))
    material.textureCoordinateTransform.scale =
                                     SIMD2<Float>(x:planeAnchor.extent.x*20,
                                                  y:planeAnchor.extent.z*20)
    material.textureCoordinateTransform.rotation = 0.5

    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: planeGeometry, materials: [material])
    model.position = [planeAnchor.center.x, 0, planeAnchor.center.z]
    self.addChild(model)
}
```

While this method works, if you believe that there are other methods that are more suitable for my use case, please do share them. Thanks!